# Isotropy of skew-Hermitian forms over division algebras

Tags: quadratic-forms, division-algebras, involutions, hermitian

Assume char(F) $\neq$ 2.

Let $D$ be a central division algebra over a field $F$ and $h: V \rightarrow D$ be an anisotropic skew-Hermitian form. We can easily see that $h_{\bar{F}}$ is totally hyperbolic (consisting of orthogonal sums of hyperbolic planes) by skew-symmetry.

**Question**: Does there exist a field extension $L$ over $F$ such that $[L:F] < ind(D)$ and $h_{L}$ isotropic? In particular, is it possible to find $L$ such that $[L:F] = 2$ as in the case of quadratic forms (i.e. if $q \cong <a,b,...>$ then setting $L = F(\sqrt{-ab})$ implies $<1,-1> \subset q_{L}$)

Comment: Skew-hermitian with respect to which kind of involution? Does $D$ has a symplectic involution ? orthogonal involution ? unitary involution ?

Anyway, in the case where $D$ is a quaternion algebra, the answer is obviously NO.